# system.windows.forms.htmlelement refference error in vs2012 professional

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

uable to reference `system.windows.forms.htmlelement` class in vs studio 2012 pro edition.I am using .net 4.5 and cant seem to get a solution. Any help regarding this issue will be heavily appreciated.

Comment: `system.windows.forms.htmlelement` is a class not a namespace

Comment: hello! thanks you for replying, I am uable to add the class in my c# document using system.windows.forms.htmlelement

Comment: Have you added reference to System.Windows.Forms.Dll?

Comment: @Haris Hasan yes I have referenced system.windows.forms dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced correctly i.e. like this

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and not like this

```
using System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement;
```

and your target framework(Project Properties-->Target framework) is one of the below

**.NET Framework**
Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

**.NET Framework Client Profile**
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1